# Android in-app purchase Billing client is crashing my app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing

When I just initiate the billing client for the inApp purchase, the app crash immediately at this line:
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(Profileowner.this).setListener(this).build();

I have implemented the PurchasesUpdatedListener and went through the https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview
full code for billing below:

```
public void billing(){

        //List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList = null;

        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(Profileowner.this).setListener(this).build();


        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"success to connect billing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"fail to connect billing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"you are disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //add a pay button
        ImageButton pay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pay);
        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (billingClient.isReady()){

                    SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSkusList(Arrays.asList("premium_3"))
                            .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                            .build();
                    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK){
                                //something to add here

                                loadSkus(skuDetailsList);
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"cant query product",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"billing clinet not ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void loadSkus(List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                .build();

        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }
```

Comment: please add a crash log.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually I have checked the crash log and noticed that I need to add the .enablePendingPurchases() to the billing client builder.

Comment: Yes exactly.. according to new billing updates you have to add .enablePendinfPurchase()

Comment: you saved my day. i had same issue and it solved after adding enablePendinfPurchase()